# How can you make a separate page reload when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like a page to be reloaded when the user press a button on the index.

Here what it looks like...

-index.php

```
<h1>Press the reload button to reload main.php</h1>
<a class="btn" id="reload">Reload</a>
```

-main.php

```
<h1>When the button is pressed on index this page should reload.</h1>
```

Basically there should be two devises one on index.html and the other on main.html. When the reload button is pressed the other device should reload.

Sorry for the lack of code, I looked and couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: This is not a menial task. In order for the two devices to affect each other all traffic needs to go through the server, client side JS alone is not enough, and both devices need to be in sync with server events. To do that you'll need to use either AJAX polling or preferably WebSockets. Once that's set up you can have Device1 make the request to the server. The server should then inform Device2 that it needs to refresh itself. As I said before, there are a lot of things to setup here, and a lot of code to write before you even get to this stage.

Comment: AJAX polling or something similar is required for this. You have to write server side code. The index.php page should make a server call when the button is pressed and turn on the indicator on server side (can be done through DB for example). On the other hand, main.php should keep polling from the server and check status of the indicator. It should reload only when it find the indicator 'on'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both pages are running in the same browser (and both are not in private/ingonito mode) you can use local storage events.

```
document.getElementById('reload').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
   window.localStorage.setItem('window-event', JSON.stringify({reload: "main.php"})); 
});
```

and in main.php:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function (evt) {
    if (evt.key === 'window-event') {
        var msg = JSON.parse(evt.newValue);
        if (msg.reload === 'main.php') {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: web workers can also exchange messages between windows, but web workers are more complex to set up and maintain and may fail when dozens of windows are open.